# Move selected variation price below product Add-ons form in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I have the official [WooCommerce Product Addon's](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/) plugin and I am using it on a variable product. however I would like the price to show above the add to cart button instead of below the variation select list as it doesn't now.

I have looked everywhere and I have moved the price for single products to below the short description but can not work out out to do this for variable products with product add-ons.

Screenshot showing current location and desired location:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce [Product Addon's](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/) plugin displays already a custom pricing table just before add to cart buttons, where the selected variation price is displayed, with the selected option pricing with the subtotal:

[image]

You can't only **move the displayed selected variation price alone**, as it's driven by javascript on live selection event and grouped with variation availability and variation description (if any).

**So what you can do is:**

1) To move the variation price with its availability and description before add to cart button using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'reposition_display_for_variable_products', 10 );
function reposition_display_for_variable_products() {
    global $product;

    if( $product_addons = $product->get_meta('_product_addons') ) {
        if( sizeof($product_addons) > 0 ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 16 );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

But it will be displayed after the custom "Addon's" pricing table:

[image]

---

2) hide the Woocommerce variation price *(as it's already displayed by the custom "Addon's" pricing table)*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'hide_variation_selected_price', 10, 3 );
function hide_variation_selected_price( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if( $product_addons = $product->get_meta('_product_addons') ) {
        if( sizeof($product_addons) > 0 ) {
            $data['price_html'] = '';
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

3) Use both together, moving the variation availability and variation description after "Addon's" pricing table and before add to cart button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.price').insertAfter('.sauce')
```

a front-end solution (just put the right selectors)

Answer (score 0):

To move the Product Add-Ons Totals placement you can add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
if( isset($GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display']) ){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_addons_end', array( $GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display'], 'totals' ), 10 );
}
```

And if you want to add it back:

```
if( isset($GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display']) ){
  add_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display'], 'totals' ), 10 );
}
```

You have to make sure of two things though:

1. You have to pass the id (or some id) as parameter to your new hook.
2. The JS that generates the totals looks for the `#product-addons-total` inside some `.cart` element.